# Django custom signals

Tags: python, django, arguments, signals

So when creating a signal, we make a `signals.py` file that looks as such:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

some_signal = Signal(providing_args=["arg_1","arg_2",...,"arg_n"])
#...
```

now my question is, what if the arguments you are going to provide are not always going to be the same? **How would you create a signal with this kind of flexibility?**

Comment: where this code should live?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you [read the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#defining-signals)

> All signals are django.dispatch.Signal instances. The providing_args is a list of the names of arguments the signal will provide to listeners. **This is purely documentational, however, as there is nothing that checks that the signal actually provides these arguments to its listeners.**

and if you look at the signature for the `send` method:

> Signal.send(sender, **kwargs)

you will notice that it just takes a single argument and however many keyword arguments you want, so you can send as many things as you like to your signals listeners

Comment: I can't believe I missed that when I went through the documentation. Well thanks!